# Is there a way to delete scores in Apple's Game Center programmatically?

Tags: center, gamekit

I did not find a way in the GameKit documentation to delete a player's score from within my app. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm hoping Apple does more work on GameKit and provides more management tools (e.g. score/category/player deletion, modification, etc.) for developers.

Answer (score 10):

Happily, Apple responded to the fake score problem and now there's a more convenient and efficient solution for managing fake scores compared to sending an e-mail:

> *Apple Announcement from October 28th, 2013:* **Manage Game Center Leaderboard Scores**
>
> You can now view and manage the top 100 scores and usernames for all
>   of your Game Center leaderboards. Protect your legitimate players by
>   signing in to iTunes Connect to delete fake scores or block players
>   that post fake scores. You can also restore scores and players within
>   the same time period. To learn more, read the Managing Game Center
>   Leaderboard Activity section in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/15_GameCenter/GameCenter.html).

Unfortunately, there's still no programmatic way to do this, but at least it's something.

Answer (score 5):

As of 9/13/17, the procedure to manage leaderboard scores is:

1. log in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com
2. Click on My Apps
3. Click on app containing target leaderboard
4. Click on "Features" (top bar)
5. Click on "Game Center" (side bar)
6. Under "Group Leaderboards" click "More"
7. In popup, click "Manage Scores and Players"

It takes a few seconds for the table to populate, so be patient.  You can only Remove or Block the top 50 entries.

Comment: Seems in 2020 it's not possible? `Manage Scores and Players` is not showing..

Answer (score 3):

The link provided in the announcement from Apple on 28th October 2013 no longer works.

However, it is no longer necessary to contact iTunes to delete a leaderboard score or block a user. Instead you

- log in to your iTunesConnect account,
- open "Manage your Apps"
- open the app with the Game Center leaderboards
- open "Manage Game Center"
- in the "Leaderboards" section you will find the button "Manage scores and players"

Here you can delete a score or block a player

Comment: I think this is outdated too.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://adcdownload.apple.com/ios/getting_started_with_ios_4.1/gettingstartedwithgamecenter.pdf), you'll need to email *itunesconnect@apple.com* to report cheating to remove scores.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, some where, you can't - I think it was on Apple's developer site. You have to send them an email to remove the score.

Edit: I was wrong, it's on here, page 3

https://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/ios/getting_started_with_ios_4.1/gettingstartedwithgamecenter.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but no. Once the score is posted directly, it can't be removed unless you contact Apple, but if your app is big enough, you will not have time to remove each score.