# Can Game Center's leaderboards support a "skill level"-like system?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

Game Center's leaderboards are generally used for high-score tracking, such as tracking a user's highest score in a game and comparing it to other users' highest scores. However, what if I had a game where if a player won, their `skillLevel` went up, and if they lost, their `skillLevel` went down (for the purpose of matching up users with other users of the same skill level)? Would Game Center's leaderboards be able to support this, or are they strictly built for having scores increase but not decrease?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot delete a high score.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961926/is-there-a-way-to-delete-scores-in-apples-game-center-programmaticaly/4360299#4360299) - You need to send them an email to report cheating in scores for scores to be deleted. Its on page 3 of GameCenter guide PDF.

As a general opinion in game design, giving a system like this, can discourage the players from playing your game again and again in fear of losing their previous scores/accomplishments.

Answer (score 0):

Game center is not only support to submit High scores. It also support for achievements. So you can create achievement according to your skill levels and they you can assign that achievement to user when they get certain skill levels. But I am not sure that you can remove same achievement from the user. I guess you can just increase number of achievement instead of decreasing. Just a suggestion. So User A got 3 achievement and User B got 5 achievements. You Can give all achievement with some meaningful name.

Hope this Help you.

Comment: While I appreciate the answer, achievements wouldn't be an ideal way to track a player's skill level, at least in my situation. I'm simply wondering if high scores on Game Center can be diminished, or solely augmented.